# UIView repositioning when another UIView animates its frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation

I have 4 UIViews on a screen and another sitting on top of those that responds to slide gestures. I use an animation block to move the top UIvew (highlighted in yellow) to the left of the screen. When I then resize one of the other UIViews to be full screen, the top UIView annoyingly animates back to it's original position. There is nothing in code making this happen as far as I can see.

here is the unwanted effect:

Before Slide:

[image]

Before resizing:

[image]

After Resizing:

[image]

slide code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:        (UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut)
                     animations:^{
                         _swipeView.frame = CGRectMake(_swipeView.frame.origin.x - 327, _swipeView.frame.origin.y, _swipeView.frame.size.width , _swipeView.frame.size.height);

                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                         ;}
```

Resize code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                     animations:^{
                         _Quad2.frame = fullScreenRect;;}
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){

                         [self singleViewTrasitionComplete:_Quad2];
                     }
     ];
```

[image: StoryBoard]

Answer (score 0):

Just before you do the resize, set a breakpoint in `setFrame:` in the yellow UIView.  Then you can see who is calling it and deduce why.

Perhaps the yellow view is being positioned initially by auto layout constraints?

You are moving the yellow view by changing its frame, but if there are auto layout constraints that position it in the middle, the next time auto layout recalculates the layout it will move it back.  You usually need to change the auto layout constraints when you move (slide) a view, not change its frame.